# Powershell script to copy and paste file to previous directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm attempting to copy and paste a file to a previous directory without using files paths.

Here's what i mean:

```
Set-Clipboard File.bat
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
write-output | get-clipboard
```

Then I go to check and it's not there, what am i missing??

Thanks.

Comment: PLEASE, do not add meaningless tags.there is no reason to tag for ps2, ps3, and ps4 ... version 3 & 4 can run all the v2 stuff, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using Set-Clipboard will only copy the name of the file to the clipboard.

Why not get the file into a variable and the copy that into the new location after you change directories:

```
$file = Get-ChildItem .\File.bat
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
$file | Copy-Item
```